# Zeppelin java.io.IOException: Job aborted due to stage failure: connection closed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

**Zeppelin v0.8.0;
Spark v2.2.0**

I'm trying to run zeppelin notebook (read data from cassandra):

```
val item = spark.
    read.
    format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
    options("table" -> "raw_cashbox_documents", "keyspace" -> "cashboxdocumentsindex" )).
    load().
    first()
```

But received exception (**java.io.IOException: Connection from /ip:port closed**):

```
ERROR [2019-01-24 12:21:56,626] ({task-result-getter-1} Logging.scala[logError]:70) - Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
 INFO [2019-01-24 12:21:56,627] ({task-result-getter-1} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
 INFO [2019-01-24 12:21:56,627] ({dag-scheduler-event-loop} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Cancelling stage 1
 INFO [2019-01-24 12:21:56,628] ({dag-scheduler-event-loop} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - ResultStage 1 (first at <console>:63) failed in 0.075 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Connection from /ip:port closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:108)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:182)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1403)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:912)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:826)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible reason is wrong version of spark. You can specify spark version in **conf/zeppelin-env.sh** [config](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#1-export-spark_home). For me Spark **v2.3.2** fixed the problem.